# Best way to version control config files under home (~) with git

Tags: git, version-control

I would like to version control my config files and scripts under `~` such as `.bashrc`, `.vimrc`, `.bash_profile` etc.. but that would require a `git init` in the home folder which would interfere with other git repos below home and which will require adding all other files to `.gitignore`.

What would be the best way to do it? I was thinking of setting up a repo with all the config files in a dedicated folder and them symlinking them to their original locations but that would require extra steps to create symlinks for all the newly added files on all boxes where I need to sync and possibly synlinks might not work with all apps.

What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.gitignore` supports patters, so you could use it to enumerate the files you want to control:

```
#Ignore all
/*

#But not these
!.bash*
!.vimrc
!etc...
```

That's all.

BTW, if git sees a sub-folder which has `.git` in it - the sub-folder is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I see at least two ways how to resolve the issue. Let's assume all repositories are stored under `~/mygits`.

1. This directory is explicitly dedicated as a container for all your git repositories and declared in `.gitignore`

```
~/.bash_profile
~/.bashrc
~/.git/*
~/.gitignore
~/mygits/**
```

Example of `.gitignore`

```
$ cat .gitignore
mygits
```

2. put the target repository (let's call it as `mydotfiles`) under `~/mygits` next to other repositories ...

```
~/mygits/mydotfiles/bash_profile
~/mygits/mydotfiles/bashrc
```

... and create links to the files

```
ln -s mygits/mydotfiles/bash_profile ~/.bash_profile
ln -s mygits/mydotfiles/bashrc ~/.bashrc
```

In my opinion the second way is better because you don't need to think of preventing to put other stuff from homedir to this repository.

Finally, hope my explanations are clear.